# Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call

Tags: gwt, tomcat, gwt-rpc

I tried developing GWT application on windows. I am got an error in tomcat log while running my GWT application when I running the project to netbeans in ubuntu. please help me?

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log 

    SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
    com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.vision.mil.client.dto.LoginDTO com.vision.mil.client.rpc.LoginService.processLogin(com.vision.mil.client.dto.MsUserDTO)' threw an unexpected exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'vision-mil2'
    Error Code: 1049
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown database 'vision-mil2'."

It seems that database hasn't been created.

Make sure that database directory has not read-only permissions, and make sure that database is really created.

Comment: The database is already created. how to make sure database directory in ubuntu?

Comment: Try to execute "chmod a+rwx yourFolder". It will set write permissions to the specified folder.

Comment: http://java-error-messages.blogspot.com/2011/04/commysqljdbcexceptionsjdbc4mysqlsyntaxe.html - maybe it'll help. You should figure out why it can't find your database. (it is not gwt or tomcat point)